# a grade B or the grade B - which article to use?

Tags: articles

Which article should be used in this sentence?

I got **the/a** grade B today at school.

Comment: Neither. It would be “I got **a** B on (this assignment) in school today.”

Comment: Or "My grade was B".

Comment: @ Ayden Ferguson How come you say neither when in your other comment which you have deleted already you said that you would say "the grade B"?

Answer (score 1):

You use the [definite article](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/definite-article-the) when you are talking about one specific thing or group of things. If you say "I got the grade B", that B must be specific, for example you might say:

> Only one person got a grade B in this test. I got **the** grade B.

If you are not talking about a specific thing, for example if many people got a grade B and you were one of them, you use the indefinite article "I got **a** grade B".

Note that, as this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got%20a%20grade%20B%2C%20got%20a%20B&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20grade%20B%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20B%3B%2Cc0) shows, the word **grade** would usually be omitted, for example "I got a B". The same rules for articles apply whether **grade** is included or not.

Comment: Is this British usage? No one would say "I got [a|the] grade B" in American English and it sounds very strange. We would just say "I got a B." We would also say **on** a test, not **in** a test. Your explanation of "a" vs. "the" still applies ("only one person got a B on this test, and I got the B") but the example sentence is odd in Am.E.

Comment: @TypeIA Good point. I have added a note to my answer.

Comment: @TypeIA Are you saying that "the grade B" is grammatically incorrect or are you referring to the conventional way of saying it by the majority of people you have come across? These are two completely different things.